# How can I use a left margin to indent text and make it vertical centered in a table cell and change that texts font features line by line

Tags: html, css, wordpress, margins, font-style

This is the code I currently have within my table and I want to be able to change font features line by line in th col span 2 block that has a background color of #ce000.

NOTE: I know this is poorly formatted code and I'm working within wordpress using HTML to create the homepage. There are likely WAY easier ways to do this, but right now those are the constraints I am working with. Thanks!

```
<center><table>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
     <th style="border-style:solid; background-color:#000;border-color:#FFF;border-width:medium;font-size:17px;vertical-align:top;padding:15px;height:100px;width:50%;" colspan="4">
    
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                <th style="border-style:solid; border-color:#FFF;border-width:medium;font-size:17px;vertical-align:top;padding:15px;height:450px;width:50%;background-color:#008080;" colspan="2">
    
    </th>
    <th style="border-style:solid; background-color:#ce0000;border-color:#FFF;border-width:medium;font-size:17px;vertical-align:center;padding:15px;height:450px;width:50%;" colspan="2">
    
    <div style="text-align:left;margin-left:60px;font-weight:normal;background-color:transparent;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:left;color:#fff;"><font style"font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;display:inline-block;">TESTING GROUNDS<BR></font>
    This is a test of centered text that is also<br>left justified. Does it work?<BR>
    <button style="border: none;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 15px 32px;
    background-color:transparent;
      font-size: 25px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
        color: #fff; 
      border: 5px solid #fff;">YAY! IT WORKS!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </th></tr>
            <tr>
    
     <th style="border-style:solid; background-color:#000;border-color:#FFF;border-width:medium;font-size:17px;vertical-align:top;padding:15px;height:100px;width:50%;" colspan="4">
    
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                <td style="border-style:solid; border-color:#FFF;border-width:medium;font-size:17px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:15px;height:600px;width:25%;background-color:#0000FF;"> 
            </td>
                 <td style="border-style:solid; border-color:#FFF;border-width:medium;font-size:17px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:15px;height:600px;width:25%;background-color:#0000FF;">
    
    </td>
    
    
     <td style="border-style:solid; border-color:#FFF;border-width:medium;font-size:17px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:15px;height:600px;width:25%;background-color:#0000FF;"></td>
     <td style="border-style:solid; border-color:#FFF;border-width:medium;font-size:17px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:15px;height:600px;width:25%;background-color:#0000FF;">
                    </td>
                        </tr>
                            </tbody>
                                </table>
    </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I answered my own question.

The div blocks were throwing me off. Looking at poorly written code for hours is bound to cause problems. Oh well.

```
<font style="font-weight:bold;font-size:25px;font-color:#ffffff;">TESTING GROUNDS<BR></font>
<font style="font-weight:normal;font-size:18px;font-color:#ffffff;">This is a test of centered text that is also<br>left justified. Does it work?</font><BR>
<button style="border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 32px;
background-color:transparent;
  font-size: 25px;
font-weight:bold;
    color: #fff; 
  border: 5px solid #fff;">YAY! IT WORKS!</button>
</th>
```